# Does NetSuite support adding analytics tracking to an arbitray web page?

Tags: analytics, netsuite

I know you can use Google Analytics to track links and user actions, etc. Is there a way to do this with NetSuite on an external site? Ex. I have a WordPress driven website can I use NetSuite for all my analytics needs?

I've looked through the developer documentation for NetSuite and the API but cannot find what I'm looking for. From what I can tell, I can only pull analytics data out of NetSuite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dnr Save your money; Use GA.

FWIW I don't know anyone using Netsuite analytics as their primary analytics package.

Google Analytics works quite well and even though it doesn't give you quite the same Netsuite specific reports I'm not aware of anything in the NS analytics you can't infer from GA.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, unfortunately NetSuite is a requirement in this instance. The current issue I'm trying to solve is gaps within customer life cycle data so I'd like to have as much analytics data in one place as possible.Is there a way to inject GA events into the NetSuite process? So basically, the exact opposite of my original question.

Comment: I'm sure this could be hacked but that's likely a lot of work for no benefit. Why would NS be a requirement? GA provides a coherent view across as many hosts as you need.

Comment: Client has been using it for a while and is not happy with the gaps in their analytics. This has been helpful, thanks!